# Unpivot data t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I have the following table '#temp':

[image]

Output should be the following:

[image]

I am able to manage to unpivot 1 column + value with the following code:

```
select cat
,b.Valuecat,b.[Values] from #temp
cross apply (values(Value1,'Value1'),(Value2,'Value2')) b([values],Valuecat)
```

What should I do to unpivot also Name1 & Name2 to get desired output?

Comment: Add them to the `VALUES` clause in your `CROSS APPLY`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to the same `VALUES` table construct...

```sql
select t.cat,
       V.Valuecat,
       V.[Values],
       V.Names,
       V.Namecat
FROM #temp t
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(t.Value1,'Value1',t.Name1,'Name1'),
                        (t.Value2,'Value2',t.Name2,'Name2')) V([values],Valuecat,Names,Namecat)
```