# Pivot data T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to pivot it to the following table:

[image]

I tried to work with the following example:
https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/
But in this case a `SUM` operator is mandatory.
I don't want to use the `SUM` operator for my data.

What would be the best approach to go.
Eventually I want to use the data again, I want to prevent that I need to make a lot of "left join" statements like the following:

```
select table_a.Cat,one.number as number1, one.namevalue as Name1, two.number as number2, two.namevalue as name2
from table_a 
left outer join (
    select *
    from #temp
    where numbercat = 'number1'
) as one on table_a.cat = one.cat
left outer join (
    select *
    from #temp
    where numbercat = 'number2'
) as two on table_a.cat = two.cat
```

I am able to unpivot the numbercat & number with the following code:

```
select *
from 
(
  select cat, numbercat, number
  from #input
) src
pivot
(
  min(number)
  for numbercat in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

What should I do to also incorporate the Namecat & namevalue data?

Comment: Use MIN or MAX then. Or `STRING_AGG`. You have to use *something*. The server can't decide by itself which of the multiple possible values to return in each column. Should it return `NULL`? `Paul`? What if there are 3 or four names?

Comment: To pivot you need to aggregate, pivoting is a form of aggregation. I must also admit, it seems odd that you are [unpivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250827/unpivot-data-t-sql) your data only to pivot it back to again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: @larnu, I unpivot it and then I order the data, so for CAT B, first number becomes 1 and second number becomes 20. Then I want to pivot it again.

Comment: Apart from that you have replaced the empty string values with `NULL`, @Zayfaya83 , I see no difference in your [original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdAMI.png) in your original question and the [expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJacF.png) in this question. And replacing `''` with `NULL` is trivial: use `NULLIF`.

Comment: I think the data adjustment I do after unpivot is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that conditional aggregation is usually simpler and more versatile than `pivot`:

```
select cat,
       max(case when numbercat = 'number1' then number end) as number1,
       max(case when numbercat = 'number2' then number end) as number2,
       max(case when namecat = 'name1' then name end) as name1,
       max(case when namecat = 'name2' then name end) as name2
from #temp
group by cat;
```